# Receiving a response when writing using ionic Ble

Tags: ionic-framework, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, response

I'm currently trying to receive a response packet when writing to a characteristic using ionic ble. However, I am not able to turn on notifications to receive responses since in the properties of the characteristics write is only true. There is no mention of notify, therefore i cannot turn on notifications. Is there a way that I can enable notify for my ble device so i can turn on notifications or any sort of work around to start receiving responses?

Thank You your help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for [this](https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-ble-central#startnotification)?

Comment: If your BLE device does not allow notifications you can't enable it